# SQL Not A Single Group Group Function

Tags: sql, sqlplus

Okay guys here is the question.
I have to list the department ID, department name, count of sales reps, and average commission rate for each department. Also I need to Group by department, and sort by average commission rate in ascending order.

I am receiving an error at line 1 under the De.Dept_ID saying that is not a group by expression

Here is my code:

```
 SELECT DE.Dept_ID as DeptID, Dept_Name as DeptName, COUNT(SR.Sales_Rep_ID) as SalesRepCount,
 Comm_Rate as AvgCommRate  
 FROM DEPT_arb DE, SALES_REP_arb SR, COMMISSION_arb C
 WHERE DE.Dept_ID = SR.Dept_ID AND
 Comm_Rate = (SELECT AVG(Comm_Rate) FROM COMMISSION_arb WHERE SR.Comm_Class = C.Comm_Class)
 GROUP BY Dept_Name
 ORDER BY C.Comm_Rate;
```

I appreciate the input

Comment: You need to use a GROUP BY clause if you call any aggregate functions.

Comment: When I do a GROUP BY on Dept_Name I get a "Group by not properly ended" error. And yes, I do have a semi-colon after it.

Comment: Can you edit the question to have `GROUP BY`? Do you `GROUP BY DE.Dept_ID as Dept_ID, Dept_Name`? Also, `AVG(Comm_Rate) AS AVGCOM`?

Comment: Added a group by, but I am now receiving a different error. Just updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DE.Dept_ID as Dept_ID, 
        Dept_Name, 
        COUNT(SR.Sales_Rep_ID) as NumOfSalesR, 
        AVG(Comm_Rate) as AVGCOM 
FROM DEPT_arb DE, SALES_REP_arb SR, COMMISSION_arb C
WHERE DE.Dept_ID = SR.Dept_ID 
GROUP BY E.Dept_ID, 
         Dept_Name, 
ORDER BY C.Comm_Rate;
```

You may also consider properly joining the tables, for i.e.:

```
SELECT  DE.Dept_ID as Dept_ID, 
        Dept_Name, 
        COUNT(SR.Sales_Rep_ID) as NumOfSalesR, 
        AVG(Comm_Rate) as AVGCOM 
FROM DEPT_arb DE
JOIN SALES_REP_arb SR on DE.Dept_ID = SR.Dept_Id
JOIN COMMISION_arb C on SR.Comm_Class = C.Comm_Class
GROUP BY E.Dept_ID, 
         Dept_Name, 
ORDER BY C.Comm_Rate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a group by.

```
SELECT DE.Dept_ID as Dept_ID, Dept_Name, 
  COUNT(SR.Sales_Rep_ID) as NumOfSalesR, 
  Comm_Rate as AVGCOM 
FROM DEPT_arb DE, SALES_REP_arb SR, COMMISSION_arb C
WHERE DE.Dept_ID = SR.Dept_ID 
   AND Comm_Rate = (SELECT AVG(Comm_Rate) 
                    FROM COMMISSION_arb 
                    WHERE SR.Comm_Class = C.Comm_Class)
GROUP BY DE.Dept_ID, Dept_Name, Comm_Rate
```

Answer (score 0):

rewrite this way and see if it gives you what you want...

```
SELECT d.Dept_ID, d.Dept_Name, 
  Count(r.Sales_Rep_ID) NumOfSalesR, 
  c.Comm_Rate AVGCOM 
FROM DEPT_arb d, 
   Join SALES_REP_arb r
       On r.Dept_ID = d.Dept_ID 
   Join COMMISSION_arb c
       On c.Comm_Class = r.Comm_Class
Group By d.Dept_ID, d.Dept_Name, c.Comm_Rate 
Where c.Comm_Rate = 
       (Select AVG(Comm_Rate)
        From COMMISSION_arb 
        Where Comm_Class = r.Comm_Class)
Order By c.Comm_Rate;
```